# How to receive complex objects in spring 3.2 mvc?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, data-binding

How to receive complex objects in spring 3.2 mvc?

In the simple example below, I have two model classes, with a many to one relationship. When adding a new Employee object, I would like to use a html select to select it's department.

When I post to add a new Employee, I get the following error:

> Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type hu.pikk.model.Department for property department; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [hu.pikk.model.Department] for property department: no matching editors or conversion strategy found

How should I implement the editor or conversion strategy? Are there best practices, or pitfalls, one should watch for?

I've read the spring mvc documentation, and some articles and stackoverflow questions, but to be honest, I find them a little bit confusing and many times too short,too off-handed.

Models:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int employeeId;
    @NotEmpty
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="department_id")
    private Department department;
    //getters,setters
}

@Entity
public class Department {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int departmentId;
    @Column
    private String departmentName;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "department_id")
    private List<Employee> employees;
    //getters,setters
}
```

In my controller class:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
private String addNew(ModelMap model) {
    Employee newEmployee = new Employee();
    model.addAttribute("employee", newEmployee);
    model.addAttribute("departments", departmentDao.getAllDepartments());
    return "employee/add";
}
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
private String addNewHandle(@Valid Employee employee, BindingResult bindingResult, ModelMap model, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        model.addAttribute("departments", departmentDao.getAllDepartments());
        return "employee/add";
    }
    employeeDao.persist(employee);
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("added_employee", employee.getName());
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "employee added...");
    return "redirect:list";     
}
```

In add.jsp:

```
<f:form commandName="employee" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/employee/add" method="POST">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><f:label path="name">Name:</f:label></td>
            <td><f:input path="name" /></td>
            <td><f:errors path="name" class="error" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><f:label path="department">Department:</f:label></td>
        <td><f:select path="department">
                <f:option value="${null}" label="NO DEPARTMENT" />
                <f:options items="${departments}" itemLabel="departmentName" itemValue="departmentId" />
            </f:select></td>
            <td><f:errors path="department" class="error" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Add Employee">
</f:form>
```

Comment: What you should do is show a dropdown list of `Department` names, but post only the department's ID. You can then retrieve the `Department` and set it in the new `Employee`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis If I'm not mistaken, this is what I've been doing in the jsp. The problem is, when the controller receives the POST, it doesn't know how to convert the id string to a Department object. If I understand correctly, I have to implement and register a Converter<String,Department> for this. I would like to know if there are best practices to this. For example, how to package this thing, what is better, editor or converter, Should I query the database in the Converter, or are there better ways? etc...

Comment: It's trying to convert an id to a `Department` because the request parameter name is `department`. If you change it (don't use `form` tag lib for this) to an `<input name="departmentId">` and add a `@RequestParam` for it, you can then query the `Department` object from some DAO layer and call the `Employee` setter for the `Department`. I think it is better to do this here than in any `Converter`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, when the controller receives the POST, it doesn't know how to convert the id string to a Department object.
I've found that there are basically three ways to solve this problem:

1. Not using spring form jstl, but a simple html select with a custom name, and in the Controller reading it with @RequestParam, accessing the database, and populating it.
2. Implementing the Converter interface, and registering it as a bean.
3. Implementing the PropertyEditor interface. Doing this is easier by extending the PropertyEditorSupport class.

I was going with the third option. (Later when I will have some time, I will edit this answer with the first two options explored.)

### 2. Implementing the Converter<String, Department> interface

```
@Component 
public class DepartmentConverter implements Converter<String,Department>{
    @Autowired
    private DepartmentDao departmentDao;
    @Override
    public Department convert(String id){
        Department department = null;
        try {
            Integer id = Integer.parseInt(text);
            department = departmentDao.getById(id);
            System.out.println("Department name:" + department.getDepartmentName());
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            System.out.println("Department will be null");
        }
        return department;
    }
}
```

In the spring beans configuration file:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService"/>
<bean id="conversionService"
  class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="converters">
        <list>
            <bean class="package.DepartmentConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

### 3. Extending the PropertyEditorSupport class

```
public class SimpleDepartmentEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {

    private DepartmentDao departmentDao;

    public SimpleDepartmentEditor(DepartmentDao departmentDao){
        this.departmentDao = departmentDao;
    }
    @Override
    public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        Department department = null;
        try {
            Integer id = Integer.parseInt(text);
            department = departmentDao.getById(id);
            System.out.println("Department name:" + department.getDepartmentName());
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            System.out.println("Department will be null");
        }
        setValue(department);
    }
}
```

Inside the Controller, I needed to add an @InitBinder:

```
    @InitBinder
    protected void initBinder(HttpServletRequest request, ServletRequestDataBinder binder) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Department.class, new SimpleDepartmentEditor(departmentDao));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For my opinion you've encounterd next situation here. When Spring trying to deserialize `Employee` entity which was received in `addNewHandle` it found property `department` of type of String but in target entity it has `Department` type, then, because you have no conversion regsieterd for such kind of conversion, it fails. So, to solve this issues you can implement own converter ([Converter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/convert/converter/Converter.html)) that gets String and returns `Department` and regsiter it in `conversionService` or you can implement own JSON deserializing strategy by overriding [Jackson JsonDeserializer](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.1.2/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/JsonDeserializer.html) and annotating `department` property with `@JsonDeserialize(using=<your Jacson custom deserializer>.class)`. Hope this helps.

Comment: JSON has no place here. This is a form and the `<input>` elements will be url-encoded form parameters.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to my mistake. You're right. But i still suppose that issue could be fixed by introducing custom 'Converter<String, Department>'.

Comment: I don't recommend doing this in a `Converter`. You would probably want to retrieve the `Department` and create the `Employee` in the same transaction. It would be hard to do this if you retrieved the `Department` in a `Converter`.

Comment: While Spring deserialize form into target entity, it creates target entity object and then iterates overtform properties and trying set appropriate fields in target entity object. While setting target entity object field Spring try to convert from source form property value to target field value by means of type conversion and can use appropriate Converter. Thus, we don't need Converter for whole Employee entity, but we need Converter for department property. Correct me if i'm wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is correct. In this case, the `Employee` is a new object, not yet persisted. But we can assume that the `Department` exists in persistent storage and that's the one OP is referring to.